# User model with Mongoengine and Django

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have 2 types of users say `UserA` and `UserB`. In my model I have

```
from mongoengine import *
from django.contrib.auth import User

ClassA(User):
  fieldA = StringField()
  fieldB = StringField()

ClassB(User):
  fieldC = BooleanField()
  fieldD = BooleanField()
```

Does this mean that in my controller I can just call

```
user = ClassA()
user.fieldA = 'something'
user.save()
```

Before I had `ClassA(Document)` and `ClassB(Document)`. Or should I be inheriting both? `ClassA(Document, User)` ?

The reason I am asking is because I want to be able to use the authentication stuff that mongoengine has.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from django won't work with Mongoengine - There is a custom mongoengine `User` class you can use or extend: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/django/auth.py